# How to create a multiple criteria advance filter in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an `advanced filter` for the below table but the code below is just hiding the cells. It's working but my problem with it is if i filter something and then I drag to fill status or any other cells it will override the cells in between for example in filter mode I have 2 rows one is 1st row and the other one is at row 20 if I drag to fill status it will replace the status of all cells in between 1 and 20 and don't know how to work it out, i know this happens because I'm hiding the cells and not actually filtering them.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[Data Table][1]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

r1 = Target.Row
c1 = Target.Column

If r1 <> 3 Then GoTo ending:
If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, c1) = "" Then GoTo ending:

Dim LC As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LC = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Range("4:10000").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For r = 5 To LR

For c = 1 To LC
If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, c) = "" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(3, c) = "" Then GoTo nextc:
If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, c) = "exact" And UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c)) <> UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, c)) Then ActiveSheet.Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = True: GoTo nextr:
If Cells(2, c) = "exact" Then GoTo nextc:
j = InStr(1, UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c)), UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, c)))
If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, c) = "partial" And j = 0 Then ActiveSheet.Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = True: GoTo nextr:

nextc:
Next c

nextr:
Next r

ending:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Creating an advanced filter in code is some... well pretty advanced stuff :) It takes a lot of logic and thus code. What is it you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to be able to filter by multiple conditions from the table attached. Basically filter by all table headers to narrow down large amounts of data. The one I created it does want i need but then when i drag to fill then it will override any data in between rows say for ex row 10 and 20 i need to drag an fill row 10 and 20 as this rows will be visible but instead it will override everything in between which is not ideal.

Comment: Can someone help me with the above code as i don't know where I'm going wrong with the code. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to be able to drag and fill only visible rows? As far as I know there is no way to do that in later versions of Excel. You can copy then paste to visible cells only.

Comment: I think there is a way i need to start from scratch and create the advance filter as the code above is no filter it's just hiding the cells it's not actually filter multiple criteria it just hides the cells that don't match.

Comment: Yes it's certainly possible, but beyond the scope of this question; I'd look to cut & paste any rows that should be hidden to a new sheet and code their retreival if required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will be the answer to the question on how to create an advanced search based on multiple criteria on what the user selects in the table.

I will need a little bit of help with how to check if the user selected by mistake an empty cell I will need to make excel ignore filtering the blank cell. Also, I will need to make excel first to check if the yellow cells A3 to T3 has data in and if it has and i press the filter button will filter by the range A3:T3 and ignore the current user selection if there is no data in range A3:T3 will filter by the user selection and in the range A3:T3, if it has data will only filter by data cell that has data in them and ignore empty ones.

```
Sub advancedMultipleCriteriaFilter()

 Dim cellRng As Range, tableObject As Range, subSelection As Range
 Dim filterCriteria() As String, filterFields() As Integer
 Dim i As Integer

If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then
 MsgBox "Cannot apply filters to multiple rows within the same column. Please make another selection and try again.", vbInformation, "Selection Error!"
 Exit Sub
 End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i = 1
 ReDim filterCriteria(1 To Selection.Cells.Count) As String
 ReDim filterFields(1 To Selection.Cells.Count) As Integer
Set tableObject = Selection.CurrentRegion
 For Each subSelection In Selection.Areas
 For Each cellRng In subSelection
 filterCriteria(i) = cellRng.Text
 filterFields(i) = cellRng.Column - tableObject.Cells(1, 1).Column + 1
 i = i + 1
 Next cellRng
 Next subSelection
With tableObject
 For i = 1 To UBound(filterCriteria)
 .AutoFilter field:=filterFields(i), Criteria1:=filterCriteria(i)
 Next i
 End With
Set tableObject = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub resetFilters()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   On Error Resume Next
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
  End If

Range("A3:T3").ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call GetLastRow

End Sub

Private Sub GetLastRow()

 'Step 1: Declare Your Variables.
  Dim LastRow As Long
 'Step 2: Capture the last used row number.
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
 'Step 3: Select the next row down
  Cells(LastRow, 8).Offset(1, 0).Select

 End Sub
```